# how to use svg icons in openlayers 4 if collected from the svg file

Tags: svg, icons

the problem is the following, have the svg file format:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">

    <symbol id="gear" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
         <path fill="#inherit" stroke="#000000" d="..."/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="drill" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
         <path style="stroke:none; fill:#000000" d="..."/>
    </symbol>
<svg>
```

do the following to make this file an icon and displayed on the map. The very icon collect:
`SVG.create('img/iconsSvg.svg#gear','img/iconsSvg.svg#drill')` it can be displayed in html

```
var SVG={
    svgns:'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
    xlink:'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
    create:function(){
        let pathUse=arguments;
        var svg=document.createElementNS(SVG.svgns, 'svg');
        for (let i = 0; i < pathUse.length; i++) {
            let use=document.createElementNS(SVG.svgns, 'use');
            use.setAttributeNS(SVG.xlink, 'xlink:href', pathUse[i]);
            svg.appendChild(use);
        }
        return svg;
    }
}
```

in openlayers set the style of this:

```
function setStyleIcon(){
                return new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        img:SVG.create('img/iconsSvg.svg#gear'),
                        imgSize:[30,30]
                    })
                });
            }
```

when it crashes the error: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.

how to translate svg to canvas I do not know

but I can't put it on the map, thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution not very nice, the svg is inserted into a js file and work with it as with text, can someone come in handy:

Function set the style:

```
function setStyleSvg(type,color,scale){
            var svg=svgIcon.getSvg([['location',color],[type,'rgb(100,100,100)',true]]);
            var style=new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon( {
                src:'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,'+svg,
                scale: scale,
                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                })
            });
            return style;
        };
```

collect svg (color need rgb/rgba format "for angularJS"):

```
app.factory('svgIcon',function(){
var size=[500,500];
var cssClass="unit";
var viewBox="0 0 2000 2000";
const closeTag='</svg>';
var insert='';

function icons(icon,color,label){
    var out;
    var offset=(label)?-250:0;
    switch(icon){
        case 'truck':out+=`<path viewBox="0 0 1024 538" transform="translate(448,`+(731+offset)+`)" fill="`+color+`" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="1" d="...."/>
                `;
                break;
        case 'drill':out+=`....`;
                break;
        case 'excavator':out+=`....`;
            break;
    }
    return out;
}

this.setClass=(className)=>{
    cssClass=className;
};

this.setViewBox=(set)=>{
    viewBox=set;
};

this.setInsert=(set)=>{
    insert=set;
};

this.getSvg=(arr)=>{//([[type,color,label],[type,color,label]....])
    try {
        var svg=`<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="`+viewBox+`" `+insert+` class="`+cssClass+`" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            svg+=icons(arr[i][0],arr[i][1],arr[i][2]);
        }
        svg+=closeTag;
        return svg;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('svg not create');
    }
}

return this;});
```